# How to store returned value from a SELECT statement in a variable for future use in a Oracle SQL Script

Tags: database, oracle, variables, select

I have a SQL script which I use to initialize my test environment. I want to save `PK_ID` of a special username from my `USERS` table and use it for clearing or inserting into other tables. I really don't know how to do that. My `SELECT` statement is this:

```
SELECT PK_ID FROM "USERS" WHERE USERNAME = 'admin';
```

I searched for it and I found out that it's possible in MySQL by means of this:

```
SELECT @admin_pk := PK_ID FROM "TBL_USER" WHERE USERNAME = 'admin';
```

And Usage:

```
DELETE FROM "USER_ROLE" WHERE USER_ID != @admin_pk;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is using a PLSQL block.

```
declare
  l_id users.pk_id%type;
begin
  select pk_id
  into l_id 
  from "USERS"
  where username='ADMIN';

  delete from "USER_ROLE" WHERE USER_ID != l_id;
end;
/
```

But in this case there is no need to store the value at all.

```
delete from "USER_ROLE"
 where user_id != (select pk_id
                     from "USERS"
                    where username = 'ADMIN');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a sqlplus variable with the value in a column like so:

```
SQL> set define on
SQL>
SQL> define today_var
SP2-0135: symbol today_var is UNDEFINED
SQL> COLUMN date_column NEW_VALUE today_var
SQL>
SQL> SELECT instance_name||'_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDMONYY_HH24.MI')||'_'||USER date_column FROM v$instance;

DATE_COLUMN
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DB1_04AUG15_05.02_SCHEMA1

SQL> define today_var
DEFINE TODAY_VAR       = "DB1_04AUG15_05.02_SCHEMA1" (CHAR)
SQL> select '&&today_var' col1 from dual;

COL1
-----------------------------
DB1_04AUG15_05.02_SCHEMA1
```